# How do I submit my own translations for Android app buttons and strings?

Tags: android, translation, google-play-console, language-translation

I would like to provide my own translations for my new Android app without using the Translation Service in Google Play Console. I have already provided translations for the app descriptions but this would be for the buttons and strings in the app.

I started to upload the xml files into the Translation Service, but then decided I don't want to pay for something that I can already translate myself. What is the best way to do this?

For example, English:

```
<resources>
    <string name="SaveSetting">Save setting</string>
    <string name="ViewSettings">View settings</string>
    <string name="SavedSettings">Saved settings</string>
    <string name="settingHint">Enter the setting name</string>
</resources>

Portuguese:
<resources>
    <string name="SaveSetting">Salvar configuração</string>
    <string name="ViewSettings">Ver configurações</string>
    <string name="SavedSettings">Configurações salvadas</string>
    <string name="settingHint">Nome da configuração</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

You create multiple string files, one for each language and the phone will automatically use the one based on the OS settings

see here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization

In your case you would put your default strings in the `res/values/strings.xml` and the Portuguese ones in a `res/values-pt/strings.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this tree in your project with correct folders and strings.xml suffix:

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-b+es/
           strings.xml
       mipmap/
           country_flag.png
       mipmap-b+es+ES/
           country_flag.p
```

"es" for Spain,  "us" USA...

Take a look:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio, you can Open the translations editor and then add the translations for your app's strings on any language.
For more details check: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor